# Can I use both Document Ready and document.body.addEventListener at the same time?

Tags: jquery

Can I use both document ready and document body eventlistener at the same time?

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        alert('raj');
    });


  });
```

Comment: The best way to obtain such answer is to test it. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes @MelanciaUK I tried but it didn't work so I wanted help.

Comment: `addEventListener()` doesn't work on IE below 9. You're already using `jQuery` so why don't use it to attach the `keydown` event handler? See answer below...

Comment: Based on your comment in the mentioned answer, I believe you're not even adding the `jQuery` library to your page. So, obviously it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

This code does the following :

1. When this JS snippet will be parsed by browser it will add an event to listen for dom ready.
2. on dom ready, handler will  be invoked which in turn will add an event to listen for 'keydown' event.
3. On keydown event - you will get your alert.

Assuming you are a newbie JS. Please don't mix jQuery methods and native JS methods together.

Code should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(body).keydown(function() {
    // alert goes here.
  });
});
```

Comment: You mixed up yourself. It should be `$("body")` and not `$(document.body)`.

Comment: I am trying on fiddle but both don't show the alert. http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8vM/14/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8vM/16/

Comment: Your jsFiddle don't have the `jQuery` library included.

Comment: If you do it, yes, it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8vM/17/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8vM/18/